# How can I get val() of input field in previous div?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <label for="minLength">Min. Length <span class="units">(ft.)</span> </label>
        <input type="number" class="heartland-input form-control dimensionalValue" id="minLength" name="minLength" min="10" step="10">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <label for="maxLength">Max. Length <span class="units">(ft.)</span></label>
        <input type="number" class="heartland-input form-control dimensionalValue" id="maxLength" name="maxLength" min="10" step="10">
    </div>
</div>
```

Starting with #maxLength, I need to get the value of #minLength. It shouldn't be that hard, but I can't see to get it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to traverse the DOM, then you'd just need to go up to a parent element, over to the target element's parent, and down to the target element.  Something like this:

```
$('#maxLength').closest('div.form-group').prev().find('input#minLength').val()
```

But this is fairly brittle.  If the DOM structure changes then the code is going to have to change with it.

**However**, this isn't really necessary.  Your target element has an `id`, so you can just select on that:

```
$('#minLength').val()
```

Comment: Yes, but there are several max-min pairs. Therfore, I must create a blur listener that can apply to all of the fields, so whichever is blurred, it's corresponding min field will be targeted.

Comment: @VisWebsoft: If you have multiple elements with the same `id` then be aware that your markup is invalid and any code which uses the `id` is going to have undefined behavior.  But yes, traversing the DOM relative to the source element would work in that case.

Comment: console.log($(this).closest('div.form-group').prev().find('input#maxLength').val()); This keeps returning undefined. I had pretty much the same thing as you put, but I used parent() instead of closest().

Comment: I get your point on duplicate ids. The other fields are just similar, like 'maxDepth', 'maxWidth', etc.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it now, based on your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @David $('minLength').val() missing `#`

Answer (score 0):

while Id must be unique you can directly use

```
var minValue = $('#minLength').val();
```

if you change this to classes  and need to use prev() you can use

```
var prev_minValue = $('.maxLength').closest('.form-group').prev('.form-group').find('.minLength').val();
```